# Migrate from Grails 2.4.4 to 4.0.9 with existing JPA with hibernate conf

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have to migrate legacy **Grails 2.4.4** apps to **Grails 4.0.9**. Existing domain-plugin has JPA (Java Code) with hibernate configuration which is working perfect as expected. There are more than 200 domain entity in my app. I would like to reuse that entities.
To do that I have changed all the entity classes to groovy class and implement GormEntity and annotate class with @Artefact(DomainClassArtefactHandler.TYPE).
When I build project I am getting an below error.

C:\domain-plugin\build\tmp\compileGroovy\groovy-java-stubs\domain\aanvraag\Book.java:11: error: Book is not abstract and does not override abstract method addTo(String,Object) in Book
@javax.persistence.Entity() @grails.artefact.Artefact(value="Domain") @javax.persistence.Table(name="Book") @domain.common.annotation.TimeTravel() public class Book

C:\domain-plugin\build\tmp\compileGroovy\groovy-java-stubs\aanvraag\Book.java:45: error: name clash: instanceOf(Class) in Book and instanceOf(Class) in GormEntity have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
public abstract  boolean instanceOf(java.lang.Class<java.lang.Object> param0);

C:\domain-plugin\build\tmp\compileGroovy\groovy-java-stubs\aanvraag\Book.java:47: error: name clash: mutex(Closure) in Book and mutex(Closure) in GormEntity have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
public abstract  java.lang.Object mutex(groovy.lang.Closure<java.lang.Object> param0);

C:\domain-plugin\build\tmp\compileGroovy\groovy-java-stubs\aanvraag\Book.java:51: error: name clash: insert(Map<Object,Object>) in Book and insert(Map) in GormEntity have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
public abstract  domain.aanvraag.Book insert(java.util.Map<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> param0);

where D is a type-variable:

```
D extends Object declared in interface GormEntity
```

C:\domain-plugin\build\tmp\compileGroovy\groovy-java-stubs\aanvraag\Book.java:53: error: name clash: merge(Map<Object,Object>) in Book and merge(Map) in GormEntity have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
public abstract  domain.aanvraag.Book merge(java.util.Map<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> param0);

where D is a type-variable:

```
D extends Object declared in interface GormEntity
```

C:\domain-plugin\build\tmp\compileGroovy\groovy-java-stubs\aanvraag\Book.java:55: error: name clash: save(Map<Object,Object>) in Book and save(Map) in GormEntity have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
public abstract  domain.aanvraag.Book save(java.util.Map<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> param0);

where D is a type-variable:

```
D extends Object declared in interface GormEntity
```

C:\domain-plugin\build\tmp\compileGroovy\groovy-java-stubs\aanvraag\Book.java:61: error: name clash: delete(Map<Object,Object>) in Book and delete(Map) in GormEntity have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
public abstract  void delete(java.util.Map<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object> param0);